# SharePoint 2013 List is not searchable

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, search, crawling

I added an index to the List field the Managed Property is Searchable, the Mapped Crawled Properties is set to `'Include in full-text index'`.

the list field name is '`ShamelDisplayNameAr`' the Managed Property name is '`ShamelDisplayNameAr`' the Crawled Properties has three ('`ows_q_TEXT_ShamelDisplayNameAr`' , '`ows_r_MTXT_ShamelDisplayNameAr`' , '`ows_ShamelDisplayNameAr`')

I'm not sure which Crawled Properties I have to map to the Managed Property.
can anyone advise?

Comment: What kind of field is it? Person and group?

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, the crawled property for the **list columns** will be named like `ows_InternalColumnName`.

The crawled property for the **site columns** will be named like:

- For site columns of type Publishing HTML and Multiple line of text:   `ows_r_<four letter code>_`
- For site columns of type Managed Metadata: `ows_taxId_`
- For all other site column types: `ows_q_<four letter code>_`

As it is a list column, map `ows_ShamelDisplayNameAr` to the managed property.